# Метод шифрования гаммированием

Tags: c#, алгоритм, шифрование

Добрый день. Я реализовывал шифрование в лабораторной работе на языке c# методом гаммирования, в моей реализации значения складываются по модулю 2.
Столкнулся с проблемой, что возникают ошибки и неправильно происходит дешифровка, это происходит из-за того, что после сложения могут получиться числа большие, чем длина алфавита. Брать mod по длине алфавита не помогает. Кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой или есть идеи как это решить?

UPD код шифрования text - текст сообщения, lol[] - генерирую массив случайных значений.

```
    public override string Crypt(bool c)
    {
        int[] alphaindex = new int[alphabet.Length];
        for(int i = 0;i< alphabet.Length;i++)//расставляем индексы для букв в алфавите
        {
            alphaindex[i] = i;
        }
        string newtext = "";//выходящий текст
        int ikey = 1;//Значение для перевода словесного ключа в число
        for(int i = 0;i<key.Length;i++)
        {
            ikey += alphaindex[indexof(alphabet, key[i])];
        }
         int[] lol = new int[text.Length];//массив случайных значений по длине текста
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            lol[i] = random.Next(ikey);
        for (int i = 0;i<text.Length;i++)
        {
            newtext += alphabet[(alphaindex[indexof(alphabet, text[i])] ^ lol[i])%alphabet.Length];
        }
        return newtext;
    }
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/676188/edit))

Comment: Как вы собираетесь использовать XOR, если у вас произвольная длина алфавита, не обязательно являющаяся степенью двойки? Какой смысл этого самого XOR? Подумайте.

Comment: Гаммирование — это же не обязательно XOR. Можно, например, складывать символ исходного текста и символ гаммы по модулю длины алфавита. (Тогда гамма состоит из символов от 0 до длины алфавита). Если же хочется использовать XOR, можно складывать с гаммой только тогда, когда «переполнения» не происходит. (Тогда символ гаммы — от 0 до соответствующей степени двойки).

Comment: -XOR, к сожалению, это одно из требований к программе.
-Если использовать только когда переполнения не происходит, то шифрует нормально, но при расшифровке соответсвенно ошибки, т.к. она проводится тем же набором случайных величин и не ясно какие надо пропустить..